# About the magnetic space group creating with GAP

Tags: gap-system

I have been learning the book ["Computer Algebra and Materials Physics"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-94226-1) during this period of time.

In the chapter 9 titled by "Final Remarks", the author wrote the following:

> In my article, I have omitted several important application of the
> group theory and the algebra. One of this is the treatment of magnetic
> or color groups. Also I omitted the treatment of Lie algebra,
> important in the spin system or the study of angular momentum. As for
> the former, a package of color groups is implemented in GAP (The Gap
> Group 2017).

Since there is no example, I am still confused about the magnetic space group creating in GAP. It's well known that there are [1651 types of
magnetic space groups in total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_space_group), as shown below:

[image]

I'm not sure if all these groups can be created and manipulated in GAP currently. Any tips or examples
will be appreciated.

Regards,
HZ

Comment: In GAP, type `?ColorGroup` - it will open manual from a package, that's how you will find out that it's a [Cryst package](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/cryst.html) implementing this. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I looked through [the presumably most related section](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/cryst/htm/CHAP002.htm#SECT010) to the discussion here. There are few examples there. I still haven't been able to create a specific color group myself for the time being. OTOH, the color group concept used in `Cryst` seems rather mathematical and general than the description used by ordinary physicists.